# can I make an application from an apk file that has been decompiled?

Tags: android, codeigniter

can I make an application from an apk file that has been decompiled?
there's an app that has a very cool feature, I'd like to have one too. Is it possible to take features from other applications? For example, I want to make an app that connects to the car, and I don't know how to make the connection, can't I take it from an apk fail that i decompile?

everything. possible.

Answer (score 1):

Technically or legally?  Technically yes, but its very hard-  almost always far harder than duplicating it for yourself.  The process of doing it is called reverse engineering.  To be good at it you pretty much need to be a master programmer, understand how application architectures work (including how the Android framework works behind the scenes), and will need to be able to identify and isolate the feature.  And that will only really work if the feature is entirely client side.

Legally-  too hard to say.  Depends on what you're doing, if its patented, and your jurisdiction.  Most legal reverse engineering is done with 2 teams, one that reverse engineers the code and describes it to the other team, and one team that reimplements it and the two teams are not allowed to work together or talk to one another.  That minimizes the risk of copying the actual implementation.  Taking the code exactly as is would be a copyright violation.